# How to use `-` in the name of a Bash variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, variables

I stored a variable named `jenkins-vm="Jenkins"` while calling the variable using `echo $jenkins-vm`
I am facing error.
How can I escape "-" while using it in a variable?

Comment: you can't have variables with `-` in bash

Comment: Can you please show how you are initializing the variable?

Comment: Use an underscore instead, that's the closest thing to a dash.

Comment: Take a look at your output. When you try tho execute your command in bash: `jenkins-vm="Jenkins"` you will see the following message: `jenkins-vm=Jenkins: command not found`. So as it has already been said, the best option is to use an undersocre instead. 
`jenkins_vm="Jenkins"` and then to see the value: `echo $jenkins_vm`

Comment: As mentioned by @DigvijayS, the hyphen is not allowed in a parameter name. The reason for that is that it can clash with a parameter expansion of the form `${foo-bar}` which will check if `foo` is set, if not it returns the string `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

The hyphen or dash character `-` is not allowed in a variable name in the Bash shell. Only lowercase/uppercase ASCII letters , `_` (underline), and digits are supported, and the first character must not be a digit. Replacing the hyphen(s) in the variable name with underline characters will work, and the variable name will still be easy to read.